# Find the Laplace equation for $f(x)=\sin^3(x), a=b=1$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm working on a PDE question but before jumping to that,
we know that:
$$D_n =\frac{2}{a \sinh\left(\frac{n\pi b}{a}\right)} \int_0^a f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right),$$

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right) \sinh\left(\frac{n \pi b}{a}\right).$$

There is a related question which seems super easy bit actually I’m having trouble with the calculation of it.
The question is :

Find the Laplace equation for $f(x)=\sin^3(x),  a=b=1$.

I tried integration by parts, putting $D_n$ directly in $u(x,t)$ but I cannot simplify it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `\\` before the names of standard functions in Mathjax syntax like $\log,\sin,\cos,\arcsin,\arccos,\tan,\cot,\sec,\csc,\sinh,\cosh,\tanh$ etc. to avoid italicization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some integration by parts, you can reduce to

$$
I_1 = \int \sin (x) \sin (n \pi x) dx\\
u = \sin (n \pi x)\\
dv = \sin x dx\\
du = n \pi \cos (n \pi x) dx\\
v = - \cos x\\
I_1 = (- \sin (n \pi x) \cos x) \mid_0^1 + n \pi \int \cos x \cos (n \pi x) dx\\
= n \pi \int \cos x \cos (n \pi x) dx\\
$$

Now do integration by parts again

$$
I_2 = \int \cos x \cos (n \pi x) dx\\
u = \cos (n \pi x)\\
dv = \cos x dx\\
du = - n \pi \sin (n \pi x) dx\\
v = \sin x\\
I_2 = (\sin x \cos (n \pi x)) \mid_0^1 + n \pi \int \sin x \sin (n \pi x) dx\\
= \sin 1 \cos n \pi + n \pi I_1\\
$$

So you get

$$
I_1 = n \pi I_2\\
= n \pi (\cos (n \pi) \sin 1 + n \pi I_1)\\
I_1 = n \pi \cos (n \pi) \sin 1 + n^2 \pi^2 I_1\\
(1 - n^2 \pi^2) I_1 = n \pi \sin 1 \cos (n \pi)\\
I_1 = \frac{n \pi \sin 1 \cos (n \pi)}{1 - n^2 \pi^2}\\
$$